# Read VARCHAR2 from Oracle Database with ResultSet

Tags: java, oracle, resultset

recently started working with an Oracle Database with Java and ResultSet, and the table I want to query has the following column structure:

```
USU_PASSWORD VARCHAR2(30 BYTE) NOT NULL
```

The problem that I am having with my code is that this column is already encrypted with DES algorithm, 
my insert, update and delete queries are working like a charm, but when I wanto to query to find the row with some value on this column, the "next" attribute on the ResultSet is coming null.

When I try to take the values from the ResultSet, it doesn't even get into the while statement

```
while(resultSet.next(){ //Does not enter here, and the next property is null }
```

Some help could be nice

Regard

I add my code below

```
Sesion sesion = null; 
    ResultSet rs = null; 
    try{
        rs = executePreparedStatement(LOGIN_PREPARED_STATEMENT, new String[]{nombreUsuario, pass});
        while(rs.next()){
            sesion = new Sesion(); 
            sesion.setCarCveElectoral(rs.getString("CAR_CVE_ELECTORAL"));
            sesion.setCarEstCve(rs.getString("CAR_EST_CVE"));
            sesion.setCarFechaInicio(rs.getDate("CAR_FECHA_INICIO"));
            sesion.setCarFechaTermino(rs.getDate("CAR_FECHA_TERMINO"));
            sesion.setCarPlzCve(rs.getString("CAR_PLZ_CVE"));
            sesion.setCarPreCve(rs.getString("CAR_PRE_CVE"));
            sesion.setCarPstCve(rs.getString("CAR_PST_CVE"));
        }
        return sesion; 
    }catch(Exception ex){

    }
```

Where the executePreparedStatement function code is

```
ResultSet rs = null; 
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    try{
        if(this.connection == null){
            if(getConnection()){
                ps = this.connection.prepareStatement(stmnt); 
                for(int i = 0; i < params.length; i ++)
                    ps.setString(i, params[i]);
                rs = ps.executeQuery(); 
            }else{
                System.out.println("No se pudo conectar a la base de datos"); 
            }
        }else{
            ps = this.connection.prepareStatement(stmnt);
            for(int i = 0; i < params.length; i ++)
                ps.setString(i + 1, params[i]);
            rs = ps.executeQuery(); 
        }
    }catch(SQLException ex){
        System.out.println("Ha ocurrido un error: " + ex.getMessage()); 
    }
    return rs;
```

And the LOGIN_PREPARED_STATEMENT String is

> "select * from usuario where USU_NOMBRE = ? AND USU_PASSWORD = ?"

Comment: try to use PreparedStatement to execute the queries if you are using JDBC http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: Is your resultSet return only one record every time?

Comment: I already tried with PreparedStatement and is the same, the weirdest thing is that the ResultSet MUST return just one row, is already tested, but it doesn't, I am also reading about VARCHAR2 with Oracle, looks like it has some problems to read it as a String

Comment: You should use a prepared statement and bind the values (including the pre-hashed `usu_password` value); but with what you have, have you dumped out the final formatted string and tried running that directly? You haven't shown an `executeQuery()` call but presumably you are actually assigning `resultSet` from one of those? Showing a bit more code might be useful here.

Comment: Well, I already tried that query directly, if you need some code, I'll show it to you :
ResultSet rs = this.connection.createStatement().executeQuery(MY_QUERY); 
while(rs.next(){/**DOES NOT ENTER THIS LOOP**/}
@AlexPoole

Comment: Please show more **actual** code, both how you insert and how you query, and as Alex Poole mentions: use `PreparedStatement` and parameters, don't use a format string.

Comment: When providing more information to you question, don't add them in comments, edit it into the question itself.

Comment: What happes when you run that statement (with the values replaced) in a SQL client? Are you aware that string comparison is case-sensitive in SQL? `'Foobar'` is not the same as `'FOOBAR'` (like `String.equals()` in Java).

Comment: I know it is case sensitive, before executing any statement, I am executing toUpperCase(), all the database is on upper case

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I just edited my question, sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution already, it was a problem with my encryption, instead of DES algorithm, I used Oracle MD5 function called md5hash, so, my query would look like

```
"SELECT * FROM USUARIO WHERE USU_NOMBRE = '%s' AND USU_PASSWORD = md5hash('%s')"
```